# Why Github contents HTML with code blocks renders all lines indented except the first one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown

I am using Github API to fetch the contents of a document and display them on my page. This is the code that I am using:

```
@contents = Octokit.contents "user/repo", path: "/readme.md", accept: 'application/vnd.github.v3.html'
```

Then I am displaying the contents inside the view after calling `.html_safe`.

The problem is that everything works ok, but the lines that belong to code blocks are all indented except the first one.

See how it appears:

[image]

which is wrong of course. Note that the original content is displayed properly when viewed from Github Web interface.

The original content is this:

https://gist.github.com/pmatsinopoulos/87f81d7125124190e0c8

Does anybody have a clue how can I fix that?

Note that I am using Ruby on Rails v4 if this has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: How are you displaying this? show the code

Comment: You're using HAML, aren't you?

Comment: "Then I am displaying the contents" - it is you who displays the thing, why you blame github? :)

Comment: I am not blaming Github :-) But you are right. There has to be something on my end. I am using HAML. Indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely displaying that content in `<pre>` tag and you're using HAML. You see, `<pre>` tag is space-preserving and HAML is space-sensitive.

I had a similar problem a while ago. IIRC, haml indentation level is somehow added to all subsequent lines of content being rendered.

My memory is blurry on the details, but this is what appears to have fixed it for me, HAML's [find_and_preserve helper](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#find_and_preserve-instance_method):

```
= find_and_preserve(item['content']).html_safe
```